# Reverse the words in a string without using builtin functions like split and substring in C#

Tags: c#, string, reverse

I wrote the following:

```
    class Program
    {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string name = "Hello World"

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = name.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            builder.Append(name[i]);
        }
        string newName =builder.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(newName);

    }
}
```

I am getting "dlrow olleh " as output. I want "World Hello ".

Comment: Why would you want to reinvent the wheel, when clearly by your question you know that there are ways that this can done by using the functions that you want to exclude from the solution?

Comment: @thewisegod Probably because it is homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a quick solution which uses 2 loops.
The first loop is iterating over the string from left to right.
When it encounters a whitespace (which delimits a word) the second loop starts.

The second loop is looping through the word from **right to left**. The second loop can not go from left to right because we have no idea where the word will begin (unless we would remember where we met the previous whitespace). Hence the second loop iterates from right to left through the string until it encounters a whitespace (beginning of the word), or until the index becomes 0 (which is a corner case). The same corner case can be observed in the first loop.

Here it is :

```
String name = "Hello World";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
{
    char tmp = name.charAt(i);
    if(tmp == ' ' || i == name.length() - 1) {
        // Found a whitespace, what is preceding must be a word
        builder.insert(0,  ' ');
        for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if(i == name.length() - 1 && j == i - 1) {
                // Exceptional case (necessary because after the last word there is no whitespace)
                builder.insert(0, name.charAt(i));
            } 

            char curr = name.charAt(j);

            if(curr == ' ') {
                // We passed the beginning of the word
                break;
            }
            else if(j == 0) {
                builder.insert(0,  curr);
                break;
            }

            //builder.append(curr);
            builder.insert(0, curr);
        }
    }
}

String newName = builder.toString();
System.out.println(newName);
```

Note that this is java code but it should be straightforward to translate it to C#.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code, a solution to this problem might look something like this:

```
result = empty string
last = input.length
for i from input.length - 1 to 0
    if input(i) is whitespace or i is 0
        for j from i to last - 1
           append input[j] to result
        last = i
```

This starts at the back of the string, and loops backwards. When it finds a whitespace (or gets to the beginning of the stirng), it knows it has found a complete word and adds it to the list. The variable `last` keeps track of where the last word that got added started.

You will have to tweak this a bit to get the spaces between the words right.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can't use "built-in" functions, doesn't mean you can't write your own. What you should be learning from a task like this is how to break a problem down into a set of sub problems.

```
string Reverse(string pInput) {
   // iterate backwards over the input, assemble a new string, and return it
}

List<string> Split(string pInput, char pSplitOn) {
   // iterate forwards over the input
   // build up a new string until the split char is found
   // when it is found, add the current string to a list
   // and start the building string over at empty
   // maybe only add strings to the list if they aren't empty
   // (although that wouldn't preserve extra whitespace, which you may want)
   // make sure to add the end of the string since it probably
   // doesn't end with the split char
   // return the list
}

string Join(List<string> pWords, char pSeparator) {
   // build up a new string consisting of each of the words separated by the separator
}

string ReverseWords(string pInput) {
   // split the input on a space
   // for each "word" in the resulting list, reverse it
   // join the reversed words back together into one string, with spaces separating them
}
```

This assumes that the only whitespace that you will encounter consists of spaces. Also assumes you're allowed to use `List<T>`.